# ¿Alguna manera de restar una variable más lento? JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego en JS, y en el método del jugador a la hora de colisionar con el enemigo este pierde vida, pero como el juego corre a muchos fotogramas por seg sin parar, al entrar en contacto con el enemigo la vida le baja muy rápido, ya que es simplemente `life = life - 10`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al entrar en contacto con el enemigo no le reste la vida tan rápido? he pensando en un settime, pero al parecer no funciona, aquí la función de damage del jugador:

```
damage() {
    this.life -= 10;
    if (this.life <= 0) {
        this.life = 0;
        this.scene.scoreText.setText(`Dead: ${this.life}`);
    }else {
        this.scene.scoreText.setText(`Life: ${this.life}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda añadir el código relevante (en formato texto). Puedes leer [mcve]. Edita tu pregunta para añadir el código y poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: listo, disculpa por no hacerlo, como es algo simple no pensaba que necesitara codigo

Answer (score 0):

Aver, no se si lo que quieres es eso, pero porque no haces un `this.life -= 0.50;` , ya que si hay muchas colisiones, iras perdiendo la vida muy poco a poco

Answer (score 0):

Te pego una forma de hacerlo que puedes probar haciendo click en Ejecutar:

```js
let vidaElement = document.getElementById('vida');
let vida = 20;

refrescarVida();

function refrescarVida() {
   vidaElement.innerHTML = vida;
}

function damage() {
  if (vida > 0) {
    restarVida(vida - 5);
  }
}

function restarVida(n) {
  if (n < vida) {
    vida--;
    refrescarVida();
    setTimeout(function() {
      restarVida(n);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="damage" type="button" value="Damage" onclick="damage();"></input>
<div>Vida: <span id="vida"></span></div>
```

Por una parte tienes un elemento `vidaElement` donde vas a escribir el valor de la vida y una variable con el valor numerico de la vida llamada también `vida`.

Hay una función `refrescarVida` para refrescar el valor en la vista que cuando se le llama. pinta en pantalla el valor numérico actual de la vida.

Hay una función `damage` que lo que hace es (si aún está vivo) quitarle 5 puntos de vida. El parámetro que le pasamos es el valor de vida que queremos que tenga al final. Por ejemplo si tiene 20 de vida y queremos quitarle 5, le pasamos 15.

Por último tenemos la funcion `restarVida`. Esta función, mientras no hayamos llegado al número de vida que estamos bajando lo que hace es:

- Quitar vida de 1 en uno
- Actualizar la vista para que se vea el cambio
- Volver a llamar a `restarVida`, pero con 1 segundo de retraso (1000 milisegundos).

Puede que tengas que adaptar un poco tu código pero te puede valer de punto de partida.

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Un sistema es creando un estado intermedio que evite ser dañado, volviendo al estado normal en un tiempo determinado.
Algo parecido a esto:

```js
damage() {
    if (estado!="damage"){
      this.life -= 10;
      estado="damage");
      setTimeout(function(){
        estado="normal";
      },1000);      
    }
    if (this.life <= 0) {
        this.life = 0;
        this.scene.scoreText.setText(`Dead: ${this.life}`);
    }else {
        this.scene.scoreText.setText(`Life: ${this.life}`);
    }
}
```